# How to compare values from two separate quires but not use inner loop?

Tags: sql, csv, coldfusion, cfquery, cfhttp

I'm working on my project where I have to compare values from DB to the values from .csv file. I have used `'cfhttp'` to convert my .csv to query and then I loop over that query and another query that I used to get values from DB. Inside of those two loop I used if statements to compare my values and check if they match. Then I stored them in the lists and use those list in cfquery tags for my update. I have 14k records in DB and about the same number of records in my .csv file. My current code takes less than 2 minutes to output records from the list to the screen for testing purpose. I still did not test how long update will take. Before I run my update I would like to see if any of you would recommend any other approach for my project? Could I reduce my execution time to less than I currently have? Here is my code that I have:

```
<cfhttp name="records" columns="A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X" method="get" url="http://path to csv/temp.csv"/>

<cfquery name="getRecords" datasource="test">
    Select s.ID, f.URID, s.UR_NUMBER, CODE, f.FIELD
    From USERS s
    Left Outer Join MAPS f
    ON s.ID = f.URID
</cfquery>  

<cfset NumA = "">
<cfset NumB = "">
<cfset NumC = "">

<cfset NumD = "">
<cfset NumE = "">
<cfset updNumD = "">
<cfset updNumE = "">

<cfloop query="records">
    <cfloop query="getRecords">
        <cfif records.A EQ getRecords.UR_NUMBER>
            <cfif records.W NEQ getRecords.CODE>
                <cfif records.W EQ 'A'>
                    <cfset NumA = ListAppend(NumA,"#records.A#")>   
                <cfelseif records.W EQ 'B'>
                    <cfset NumB = ListAppend(NumB,"#records.A#")>
                <cfelse>
                    <cfset NumC = ListAppend(NumC,"#records.A#")>
                </cfif>
            </cfif>

            <cfif getRecords.URID EQ ''>
                <cfif records.W EQ 'D'>
                    <cfset NumD = ListAppend(NumD, "#getRecords.ID#")>
                <cfelseif records.W EQ 'E'>
                    <cfset NumE = ListAppend(NumE, "#getRecords.ID#")>
                </cfif>
            <cfelse>
                <cfif records.W EQ 'E'>
                    <cfset updNumD = ListAppend(updNumD, "#getRecords.URID#")>
                <cfelseif records.W EQ 'D'>
                    <cfset updNumE = ListAppend(updNumE, "#getRecords.URID#")>
                </cfif>
            </cfif> 
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Here I dump my lists to the screen:

```
<cfdump var="#NumA#">
<cfdump var="#NumB#">
<cfdump var="#NumC#">
<br>
<cfdump var="#NumE#">
<cfdump var="#NumD#">
<br>
<cfdump var="#updNumE#">
<cfdump var="#updNumD#">
```

Also I was wondering if it's possible to get out with cfhttp tag just columns that I need from my .csv? Now I'm garbing all columns from my .csv even if I use only two of them column A and W. Also is it possible to join query from `'cfhttp'` to my query from DB? If anyone can give me some advise on this project please let me know.

Comment: cflib.org has two functions that might help.  ListCompare tells you what is in one list and not the other.  ListAnd tells you what is in both lists.  With 14 K records, This is probably a better approach than query of queries.

Comment: using `arrayAppend()` instead of `listAppend()` should drastically speed up your processing. You can use `arrayToList()` if you need it to be output as a list. You can also drop the the quotes basically everywhere you're using them. i.e. `"#getRecords.ID#"` can be `getRecords.ID`

Comment: @MattBusche Why I would first store in array and then convert that to the list? That would take more time in overall process for my page. Also I'm using lists because I can place them in my WHERE clause in just run update for specific field.

Comment: It would not take more time. Each time you append an item to a list it has to create a new string in memory and delete the existing one. It is much more resource intensive than you think. `arrayToList()` takes almost zero processing time.

Comment: @DanBracuk Should I store then all records from the quires in the lists and then compare them with records from the lists from another query? Would that be more efficient than my current code?

Comment: @MattBusche Is that the only modification in my code that you would recommend? If I change to array and convert to list then how much time that will reduce to execute approximately? Thank you.

Comment: You'd save at least 95% on processing time. See this example from [cflive](http://trycf.com/gist/aecafc507929f0b59524551017974d80/acf2016?theme=monokai) 800ms for the list 5ms for the array

Comment: @MattBusche Thank you for this working example. Obviously arrays are way faster than a lists. I will change to arrays and see how that will affect my code.

Comment: ColdFusion's valueList() function already provides the list variables.  If you check for similar functions for arrays, you might find that they work with query columns.

Answer (score 2):

So I think you are only interested in data where `records.A` is equal to `getRecords.UR_NUMBER`. You could use a Query of Queries to get the intersection of the two datasets. Something like:

```
<cfquery name="intersection" dbtype="query">
  select *
  from records, getRecords
  where records.A = getRecords.UR_NUMBER
</cfquery>
```

That should give you combined dataset which you can then loop through and build up your lists. As Matt Busche mentioned in the comments, list operations are slow, so arrayAppend will be faster.

If Query or Query is too slow, then you may want to look at converting one of the recordsets to a struct (of key value pairs) as look ups are faster. For example:

```
<cfscript>
// convert to structs as key lookups are fast
dbData = {};
for (row in getRecords) {
    dbData[row.UR_NUMBER] = row;
}

csvData = {};
for (row in records) {
    if (structKeyExists(dbData, row.A)) {
        // we have a match, so build the lists here...
        writeDump(dbData[row.A]);
    }
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: I have question about Query of Queries. I never used them before and I was confused what I should use for my datasource in my cfquery tag? Since .csv file is not coming from the same DB where I'm pulling my records in second query. Your example above has just "query" for dbtype. Can I use the same thing in my code? Thanks for help.

Comment: Also I got this errorr: Comparison exception while executing =.
Incompatible Type Comparison Exception: Left hand side and right hand side of the comparator operator "=" have incompatible types.
Left hand side expression type = "VARCHAR".
Right hand side expression type = "DOUBLE".

Comment: If you were dealing with 14 records instead of 14 thousand, this would be a good answer.

Comment: @user3023588 you can use `cast` to make the datatypes match. For example `CAST(getRecords.UR_NUMBER as VARCHAR)`. As @Dan Bracuk mentioned, you'll have to try it out to see how performant it is with your datasets.

Comment: @JohnWhish I tried Query of Quires and that takes about 8min what is even less efficient than my current code with inner loop. So I'm wondering if maybe putting everything in the srtuck and then loop through the file and compare with the key from the struct will be better option?